# How To Add space in a string based on a string array if the string is present

Tags: java

How To Add space in a string based on a string array if the string is present in java.
my problem is:

```
//input string 
//314562173583721321376 

//array of string 
//{3 ,314,49, 90234,56217358, 14,3721,376,4, 789 }
//output
//3 314 56217358 3721 376


String myString = "314562173583721321376";
String inputArray[] = new String[] {"3" ,"314","49", "90234","56217358", "14","3721","376","4"," 789" };
```

this should generate this output

```
3 314 56217358 3721 376
```

this code can be used to shortlist the numbers but how do we add spaces.

```
 ArrayList<String> newArrayWithOnlyTheContainedNums = new ArrayList<>();

 for (int i =0 ;i< inputArray.length - 1 ;i++ ){

    if(myNum.contains(inputArray[i]) ){

        newArrayWithOnlyTheContainedNums.add(inputArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a homework this was a it just came in my mind, I thought of doing it but failed so I asked for help

Comment: Don't store with a space, only add a space when printing or output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Main
{  
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String date = "",neawe = "";
    String myNum = "314562173583721321376";
    String inputArray[] = new String[] {"3" ,"314","49", "90234","56217358", "14","3721","376","4"," 789" };
ArrayList<String> newArrayWithOnlyTheContainedNums = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i =0 ;i< inputArray.length - 1 ;i++ ){

    if(myNum.contains(inputArray[i])  && inputArray[i].length() >= 3){

        newArrayWithOnlyTheContainedNums.add(inputArray[i]);
    }
}



for (int i =0 ;i< newArrayWithOnlyTheContainedNums.size() ;i++ ){
  date = String.join(" ",newArrayWithOnlyTheContainedNums); 
}

System.out.println("date is = "+ date);


    }
}
```

Comment: let me check this ans

Comment: Glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Here you have one possible approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myString = "314562173583721321376";
    String[] inputArray = new String[]{"3", "314", "49", "90234", "56217358", "14", "3721", "376", "4", " 789"};

    ArrayList<String> resultArray = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i =0 ;i< inputArray.length - 1 ;i++ ){
        String num = inputArray[i];
        int matchIndex = myString.indexOf(inputArray[i]);
        if(matchIndex != -1){
            resultArray.add(num);
            myString = myString.substring(matchIndex);
        }
    }
    resultArray.forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
}
```

Comment: this only generates the result I already have, it just shortlists the array. it does not add spaces inside the initial string

Comment: @SyedUsamaAhmad the spaces was the easy thing, I've edited the last line only to print the values with a " ", how about that?